# Deprecated FB 'Share' Button to Share FB Page w/ iFrame Content

Tags: facebook, iframe, tabs, share

I am building a tab for a Facebook page, and this tab contains the deprecated share button, outlined here - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

By my understanding, the default functionality of this button is to share the URL of the page it currently lives on. But I don't want to share the url of the iFrame contents, but rather, the Facebook page, with whatever the user is currently viewing within that iFrame.

Currently, I have it hard coded to share the URL of the FB page itself but have been told by my boss that this is not what they want. The active page within the tab must also be shared along with it.

Hopefully I've made this clear enough. Thanks in advance for any help or consideration with this issue.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the various states of your app/tab are not affected by the parent document's URL, this isn't possible.